# Why am I getting an exception declaring my PFDAcroForm?

Tags: vb.net, itext

```
Private Sub WritePDF()
        Dim pdfa As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(New PdfReader("c:\temp\A.pdf"), New PdfWriter("c:\temp\B.pdf"))
        Dim form As PdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfa, True)
        form.GetField("1a").SetValue("999")
        pdfa.Close()      
End Sub
```

I'm trying to write to fields in an existing fillable PDF and getting a NullReferenceException on the Dim form line and I have no idea why.  It opens the first PDF, creates the second PDF (empty file), then breaks on Dim Form.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: Give a try to getAcroForm, not shared, with lower G...